# Android application stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7

When I wrote my code(following) in eclipse, it gave an error on the emulator that, your application has stopped unexpectedly. There is no installation error for sdk. Here is my code.

```
public class startingPoint extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    int counter1,counter2;
    Button add;
    Button sub;
    TextView display;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        counter1=counter2 = 0;
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
        display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                counter1=counter1+1;
                display.setText("Your total is "+counter1);

            }
        });
        sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                counter2=counter2-1;
                display.setText("Your total is "+counter2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning a new value to the same variable twice.

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```

I think this should be :

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```

In your code, `sub.setOnClickListener` throws a `NullPointerException` because `sub` is null.

Answer (score 1):

You have a copy&paste error, you never initialize `sub`

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub); // should be sub instead of add
```

For the next question, please take a look at your LogCat and post the stack trace as this might help us find the error easier.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting nullPointer exception because you havenot initialized sub variable. modify your code:

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```

to

```
add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);
```